# Get all posts that were published in the last 12 hours

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to get all the posts that were published in the last 12 hours. The issue I have is that it seems that my security rules won't let me. I don't understand where is my mistake.

Here are my security rules :

```
allow read : if resource.data.hour_limit > request.time;
//hour_limit is the time when the post document was created + 12 hours
```

Here is the query I am sending to my database :

```
//get the user document reference from its username
const usersCollRef = collection(db, 'users')
const userDocSnaps = (await getDocs(query(usersCollRef, where('username', '==', username)))).docs


//store the user document reference in a variable
const userDocRef = userDocSnaps[0].ref


//calculate timestamp of 12 hours ago from request time
const HOUR_LIMIT = Timestamp.fromMillis(Timestamp.now().toMillis() - Timestamp.fromMillis(hoursToSeconds(12) * 1000).toMillis())


//current query.................................................................................
const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'public_posts')
const postsQuery = query(postsCollectionRef,
        postsCollectionRef,
        orderBy('hour_limit','desc'),
        startAfter(lastPostTimestamp),
        endAt(HOUR_LIMIT),
        where('hour_limit','>',Timestamp.now()),
        limit(10),
)

const postsDocs = (await getDocs(postsQuery)).docs //this throws a missing permission error
```

I want to query all posts published by an author, stored as a reference (userDocRef) in the post document

I get this missing permission error :

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK3wM.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to query each document of the collection for the twelve hour difference, instead of applying this constraint in the security rules?

Answer (score 0):

You need `request.resource` syntax to access data

```
match /public_posts/{postID} {
    allow read : if request.resource.data.timestamp.toMillis() >= request.time.toMillis() - 43200000
```

Comment: This doesn't work because request.resource is the object sent to the db when you add/set a document with new information and I'm only getting the document